# Asp.net Identity Integration Test

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

I want write test and save user in sql ce.This my test:

```
   using (ApplicationContext context = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            var email = "Shahrooz@s.s";
            var username = "shahrooz";
            var customUserStore = SmObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>>();
            var customRoleStore = SmObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<IApplicationRoleManager>();
            var smsService = SmObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<IIdentityMessageService>();
            var emailService = SmObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<IIdentityMessageService>();
            ApplicationUserManager manager = new ApplicationUserManager(customUserStore, customRoleStore, new DpapiDataProtectionProvider(), smsService, emailService);
            context.Database.Connection.Open();
            manager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationUser { Email = email, UserName = username }, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Wait();
            var applicationUser = context.Users.Find(1);
            Assert.IsNotNull(applicationUser);
            Assert.IsTrue(applicationUser.Email == email);
            Assert.IsTrue(applicationUser.UserName == username);
            context.Database.Connection.Close();
        }
```

But CreateAsync dont store any thing in database.
What is my problem?

Comment: Does the integration test project's app.config have all of the right connection string information?

Comment: @danludwig Yes I set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
manager.CreateAsync(.....
```

this method returns an object `IdentityResult` that contains boolean for `Successful` and a list of `Errors` that you should inspect. Inspect this object for errors and if user was created.